# Make Search and Archives match homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have my homepage http://www.faberunashop.com set up as a directory. When you click on the post image, it takes you over to the artists site.  Here is the code that I used to make this happen by adding it to the functions.php:

```
function print_post_title() {
    global $post;
    $thePostID = $post->ID;
    $post_id = get_post($thePostID);
    $title = $post_id->post_title;
    $perm  = get_permalink($post_id);
    $post_keys = array(); $post_val  = array();
    $post_keys = get_post_custom_keys($thePostID);

    if (!empty($post_keys)) {
      foreach ($post_keys as $pkey) {
            if ($pkey=='url1' || $pkey=='title_url' || $pkey=='url_title') {
              $post_val = get_post_custom_values($pkey);
            }
      }
      if (empty($post_val)) {
            $link = $perm;
      } else {
            $link = $post_val[0];
      }
    } else {
      $link = $perm;
    }
    echo '<h2><a href="'.$link.'" rel="bookmark" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></h2>';
}
```

Now I want to do the same to my search and archive page. What do I adjust to make them behave the same?

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? You does your code do not work for your search and archive page?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use WordPress.

In that case you can change the layout and the behavior of your search results by creating a file with name search.php into your theme for your search results, and another file for archives that called archives.php.

For more information about Template Hierarchy for WordPress you can find here http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: both already exist in this template. I just need to know how to modify them to get the same results that i am getting from my homepage

Comment: If the above code work for home page, just copy it and paste it, and you will have the exact result on both pages.